# Cassandra CQL select query not returning records which have timestamp as clusterkey

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, nosql

Cassandra CQL: Table created with composite key and cluster key.  When I try to execute select * from partition key then I able to retrieve all data and it works for relational operator ( < or > ) too . 
But when I queried for particular cluster key using equal-to(=) operator with proper value it returns 0 rows.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE entity_data (
received_date timestamp,
entity text,
received_time timestamp,
node int,
primary key ((received_date ,entity),received_time));
```

**Data ( select * from entity):**

```
received_date              | entity | received_time            | node_id
2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400   |     NA | 2014-09-24 18:56:55+0400 |       0  |
```

**with Conditional Query:** -- here it does not work

```
select * from entity_data 
where received_date = '2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400' and entity = 'NA' 
and received_time='2014-09-24 18:56:55+0400';
(0 rows)
```

-- it returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 3):

I see what is going on.  You are using `now()` to generate a time-UUID.  But when you convert that to a `timestamp` using `dateOf()` you are truncating the milliseconds off of it.  Therefore querying for a `received_time` equal to 2014-09-24 18:56:55+0400 will yield nothing, as the `timestamp` type is still stored with the milliseconds (you just can't see it due to your `dateOf()`).

The best way to go about this, is to store your times as `timeuuid`s (NOTE: I left `received_date` as a timestamp just for purposes of the example).  Then use the `dateOf` when you `SELECT`, and use the `minTimeuuid()` function for your `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE entity_data2 (
    received_date timestamp,
    entity text,
    received_time timeuuid,
    node int,
PRIMARY KEY ((received_date, entity), received_time));

INSERT INTO entity_data2 (received_date, entity, received_time , node) 
VALUES ('2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400','NA',now(),0);

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM entity_data2 
    WHERE received_date = '2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400' AND entity = 'NA'  
    AND received_time>minTimeuuid('2014-10-08 08:13:53-0500') 
    AND received_time<minTimeuuid('2014-10-08 08:13:54-0500');

 received_date            | entity | received_time                        | node
--------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+------
 2014-09-23 15:00:00-0500 |     NA | f3b548b0-4eec-11e4-9d05-7991a041665c |    0

(1 rows)

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT received_date, entity, dateof(received_time), node 
    FROM entity_data2 WHERE received_date = '2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400' AND entity = 'NA'
    AND received_time>minTimeuuid('2014-10-08 08:13:53-0500') 
    AND received_time<minTimeuuid('2014-10-08 08:13:54-0500');

 received_date            | entity | dateof(received_time)    | node
--------------------------+--------+--------------------------+------
 2014-09-23 15:00:00-0500 |     NA | 2014-10-08 08:13:53-0500 |    0

(1 rows)
```

Basically the `dateOf()` function was designed to be used for querying data, not storing it.  Here is a blog posting that describes (in more detail) how to make this work:

[Time series based queries in Cassandra 1.2+ and CQL3](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2013/05/time-series-based-queries-in-cassandra.html)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply.. But it is not working:

Comment: for insert query I was using dateof(now()) because of this select operator not returning any value. Please tell me how to overcome this.

Comment: @madheswaran can you edit your question with your `INSERT` query, double-check your table schema to make sure it resembles what is in the question, and also provide your version number?  It will be difficult to help you any further without that information.

Comment: INSERT INTO entity_data (received_date, entity, received_time , node) 
VALUES ('2014-09-24 00:00:00+0400','NA',dateOf(now()),0);

Comment: @madheswaran Edit made.

Comment: [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.8.39 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol19.39.0                                                           CREATE TABLE entity_data2 (
    received_date timestamp,
    entity text,
    received_time timeuuid,
    node int,
PRIMARY KEY ((received_date, entity), received_time));