# select query on cassandra with where clause field as timestamp

Tags: cassandra

I need to run a select query with a where clause with field as timestamp datatype.

In scheme the datatype of SUBMIT date is timestamp

```
"SUBMIT_DATE" timestamp,

select "SUBMIT_DATE" from "MESSAGES_2016_02_18";

 SUBMIT_DATE
--------------------------
 2016-02-18 16:26:14+0530

(1 rows)
```

but when i try

```
select * from "MESSAGES_2016_02_18" where "SUBMIT_DATE"='2016-02-18 16:26:14+0530';

(0 rows)
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the desired result?

the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "MESSAGES_2016_02_18" (
  "ADDR_DST_DIGITS" ascii,
  "ID" uuid,
  "SUBMIT_DATE" timestamp,
  "TARGET_ID" ascii,
  "VALIDITY_PERIOD" timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (("ADDR_DST_DIGITS"), "ID")
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='';
```

I created a index as well as "SUBMIT_DATE" is not a primary key

```
create INDEX fetch_date ON "TelestaxSMSC"."MESSAGES_2016_02_18" ("SUBMIT_DATE");
```

Please let me know how do i fetch the details with the above query.

Comment: Can you please give your CREATE TABLE script ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "MESSAGES_2016_02_18" ("ADDR_DST_DIGITS" ascii,"SUBMIT_DATE" timestamp,
  "TARGET_ID" ascii,
  "VALIDITY_PERIOD" timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (("ADDR_DST_DIGITS"), "ID")
) ;

Comment: I cannot give the whole table as the comment limit doesnt permit it,

Comment: You can also edit your question and add your create table statement

Comment: Did you happen to INSERT your timestamp with milliseconds?  If so, this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547616/cassandra-cqlsh-how-to-show-microseconds-milliseconds-for-timestamp-columns/28549241#28549241

Comment: cqlsh:TelestaxSMSC> select blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob("SUBMIT_DATE")) from "MESSAGES_2016_02_18";

 blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(SUBMIT_DATE))
--------------------------------------------
                              1455792974740
                              1455792974740

=====================================(2 rows)yes i guess its in milliseconds:

Comment: but this blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob) function cant be used in where criteria, correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: okay able to direct comparision with epoch for timestamp datatype, ....but for me main problem occurs when i do ..............................................................cqlsh:TelestaxSMSC> select * from "MESSAGES_2016_02_18" where "SUBMIT_DATE">='1455792974740';
Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator                                                                                              here the problem is that submit_date is not a primary key but only a index, how can i run this query?

Answer (score 0):

Humm, it looks like there is a problem with timezone config. I've seen this issue before.

- what is your Cassandra version ?
- is the Cassandra server time set on UTC ?
- is the server on which you're running **cqlsh** time set on UTC ?

Comment: cassandra version is 2.0.9.

Comment: date is IST on the server, on which the cqlsh is running, cqlsh is running from the same server where cassandra db is present