# Cassandra query on timestamp column returns no values with Java's Instant type

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to figure out how I can query cassandra on a minute interval on specific dates with java 8 api.

For example, imagine I have a groups table.

```
create table groups(
group_name text,
updated_on timestamp
primary key (group_name, updated_on)
);
```

I have the following records inside the table

```
group_name    updated_on
RealGroup     2017-01-01 04:30:00-0800
RealGroup     2017-01-01 04:30:15-0800
MockGroup     2017-02-05 04:30:00-0800
```

I'd like to execute a query to cassandra like the following.

```
select * from groups where group_name = 'RealGroup' and updated_on >= 2017 01-01 04:30:00-0800 AND <= 2017-01-01- 04:30:59-0800'
```

So essentially, I'd like to get data ON THE MINUTE interval.

I am using a GroupAccessor with the datastax api.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM GROUPS WHERE GROUP_NAME = :groupName AND UPDATED_ON>= :startDate AND UPDATED_ON<= :endDate")
Result<Group> getResults(@Param("groupName") String groupName, @Param("startDate") Instant startDate, @Param("endDate") Instant endDate);
```

My question is, what would the client call look like?  Whats the correct way to send the request with java 8 api?

I'm using the following, but it's giving me odd results.

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 1, 4, 30);
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.JANUARY, 1, 4, 31);
Instant start = startDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Instant end = endDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

Result<Group> dateGroup = groupAccessor.getResults("RealGroup", start, end);
```

So in reality, this code above should return 2 rows.

```
RealGroup     2017-01-01 04:30:00-0800
RealGroup     2017-01-01 04:30:15-0800
```

but returns none.

Comment: _Odd_ how? What's unexpected?

Comment: The return is empty.

Comment: Instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC`, you want a `ZoneOffset` that represents the `-0800` you have in your CQL query.

Comment: Is there a way where I dont have to deal with zones?  Datastax doesn't support a DateTimeCodec.  So i'm only left with Instance.  To convert a datetime to an instance, I have to pass in the offset, and frankly, these zonedoffsets confuse me.  What is the -0800 exactly?  The time from greenwich?  Also, I'm confused with your response Sotirios.

Answer (score 3):

You're clustering on a column of type `timestamp`. The [`timestamp`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) type represents

> a number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as the
>   epoch: January 1 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT

When using CQLSH, you can use a integer value representing that number of milliseconds

```
INSERT INTO groups (group_name , updated_on ) VALUES ( 'MockGroup', 1485221928341);
```

or you can use

> a string literal in any of the following ISO 8601 formats:
>
> ```
> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm  
> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss  
> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mmZ  
> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ  
> yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm  
> yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mmZ  
> yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss  
> yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ  
> yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ffffffZ  
> yyyy-mm-dd  
> yyyy-mm-ddZ
> ```
>
> where `Z` is the RFC-822 4-digit time zone, expressing the time zone's difference from UTC

In your example, you've specified

```
2017 01-01 04:30:00-0800
```

which contains a timezone that is 8 hours behind UTC. But when you made your request in Java code, you created an `Instant` that's meant to represent 4:30 local time from the UTC timezone (ie. 0 offset). That's what

```
Instant start = startDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

does. So you're 8 hours off what's actually in the database. Instead, create an `Instant` from a timezone that is 8 hours behind UTC at 4:30 local time.

```
Instant start = startDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8));
Instant end = endDate.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8));
```

This should get you back the two groups that you wanted.

> Is there a way where I dont have to deal with zones?

Yes, use integer numbers (like my first example). It's just harder to reason about plain numbers than formatted strings.

Or, you can use `Z` at the end of your date string to indicate the Zulu time zone which has no offset UTC. For example,

```
INSERT INTO groups (group_name , updated_on ) VALUES ( 'MockGroup', '2017-02-05 04:31:00Z');
```

Obviously, from Java code, the `Instant` has no concept of timezone, it simply represents a timestamp, just like the type in Cassandra, so you can use it directly.

Comment: When I save an instant record with datastax's driver, the value of the timestamp in cassandra always seems to end up in human legible format, i.e '2017-01-23 06:40:43-0800' instead of an integer in milliseconds.  How do you change it?

Comment: @user1172490 That's just how CQLSH displays it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547616/cassandra-cqlsh-how-to-show-microseconds-milliseconds-for-timestamp-columns) are a couple of tricks to print it as an integer.