# Cassandra current timestamp with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra

In the below insert query when I use `dateof(now())` it is not working. But `new Date('2017-09-01 00:00:00+0000')`, this one is working.

```
router.post('/recent_activities', function(req, res, next) {
  var body = req.body;

  console.log(body);
  console.log(body.id + body.setid);

  var query = "Insert into recent_activities 
    (id, setid, companyid, activity_name, activity_date, activity_by) values( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )
  "

  client.execute(query, [body.id, body.setid, body.companyid, body.activity_name, dateof(now()), body.activity_by],
    function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        console.log('success!');
      }
    });

  res.json({ id: 201, message: 'All Success' });
});
```

I am getting a 500 internal server error.

> now is not defined

```
ReferenceError: now is not defined

at /apps/node_cassandra/routes/index.js:96:85

at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 

(/apps/node_cassandra/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next 

(/apps/node_cassandra/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch 

(/apps/node_cassandra/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 

(/apps/node_cassandra/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)


    at /apps/node_cassandra/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query ="Insert into recent_activities (id,setid,companyid,activity_name,activity_date,activity_by) values (? , ?, ?, ?, **dateof(now())**, ?)"
    client.execute(query,[body.id,body.setid,body.companyid,body.activity_name,body.activity_by], function(err, result) {
```

> adding  "dateof(now())" worked for me by adding in the insert values.

Answer (score 1):

> dateOf()
>
> Used in a SELECT clause, this function extracts the timestamp of a
>   timeuuid column in a result set. This function returns the extracted
>   timestamp as a date. Use unixTimestampOf() to get a raw timestamp.

According to documentation `dateOf` is used in select clause.

`now()` is used to generate timeuuid for inserts.

So if your column datatype is timeuuid then only you can use `now()`.
If it is timestamp insert the date as `new Date()`.

Alternatively there is `toDate` function available, which can be used in insert

[dateOf](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem...

```
client.execute(query,
[body.id,body.setid,body.companyid,body.activity_name, dateof(now()),body.activity_by],
```

...is that your code is referencing `dateof(now())` as if it is a variable local to your Node.js code.  I'd suggest putting it in quotes...

```
body.activity_name, "dateof(now())",body.activity_by],
```

...but that may not work the way you intend when it is treated as a parameter to your statement.

For this case, it may just be easier to modify your INSERT statement...

```
var query ="Insert into recent_activities 
    (id,setid,companyid,activity_name,activity_date,activity_by)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, dateof(now()) , ?)"
```

...and subsequently remove it from your parameter list.

Note that `dateOf(now())` is meant to be used with SELECT queries.  Using it with an INSERT/UPDATE has a side-effect of storing milliseconds with your time value, but not actually showing you that they are there.  See this for more info: [Cassandra cqlsh - how to show microseconds/milliseconds for timestamp columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547616/cassandra-cqlsh-how-to-show-microseconds-milliseconds-for-timestamp-columns/28549241#28549241)