# Cassandra <= on a time column

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a Cassandra table that looks something like this

```
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-04-24 02:04:57+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-06-26 13:19:03+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-06-29 06:14:00+0000
```

My requirement is to print all rows that are less than or equal to 2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000

My query is:

```
cqlsh -ksd -e "select type, timevalue from table_one where timevalue != null and timevalue<='2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000'"
```

It prints

```
 VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-04-24 02:04:57+0000
```

Since I gave <= I expected it to print

```
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-04-24 02:04:57+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000
  VmwareVirtualMachine | 2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000
```

If I do something like this:

```
cqlsh -ksd -e "select type, timevalue from table_one where timevalue != null and timevalue<='2020-05-14 06:02:24+0000'"
```

It prints the first 3 rows if I increase the time by a second. Not sure why less than or not equal to does not work in my statement.

Any help?

Comment: print timestamps with milliseconds resolution - most probably it's not `2020-05-14 06:02:23+0000`, but like `2020-05-14 06:02:23.123+0000`

Comment: I think @AlexOtt is correct.  Check my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547616/cassandra-cqlsh-how-to-show-microseconds-milliseconds-for-timestamp-columns/28549241#28549241